# ArangoDB throws "HTTP WARNING maximal header size"

Tags: arangodb, http-error

While starting up the arangodb, it throws a warning with:

> "WARNING maximal header size is 2097152, request header size is 2120118".

The logfile is flooded by this message with different header sizes.

Any suggestions which config parameter to configure to increase the limit?

Answer (score 1):

*From dothebart in ArangoDB Community Slack:*

There is only the maximum post document size in soft and hard limits. It occurs to me, that for that sort of purposes you should add a proxy in front of ArangoDB like Nginx to do the remote termination.